# How to get selected option in angular <select>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Trying to figure out how to get the id and name of the selected item in angular.  Basically brand new to js and angular so not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure its something simple I'm missing.

I have an html element that looks like:

```
 <md-input-container>
     <label>Difficulty</label>
     <md-select ng-model="difficulty" ng-change="update()">
         <md-option ng-repeat="difficulty in difficulties">
             {{difficulty.Name}}
         </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Calling an api to get the list of difficulties gives back the following json

```
[{DifficultyID: 1, Name: "Easy"}, {DifficultyID: 2, Name: "Medium"}, {DifficultyID: 3, Name: "Hard"}]
```

In my controller I have defined the method

```
$scope.update = function () {
            console.log($scope.item.Name);
        }
```

Always get an undefined for Name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-value` might be useful in this case. See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I1c1rAYWZKWJEzwqPpTd?p=preview).

```
<md-select ng-model="difficulty">
     <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in difficulties" ng-click="update(opt)">
         {{opt.Name}}
     </md-option>
</md-select>
```

I've introduced `opt` variable in order to eliminate `difficulty` duplication. In addition to that I'm doing `ng-click` on particular option instead of `ng-change` on parent `md-select`

Answer (score 2):

Your selected option should be in the model you've set in ng-model.

That said to access your selected option you should test your difficulty model in scope

```
$scope.difficulty
```

should hold your selected item.

Want to see it working try

```
$scope.$watch('dificulty',function(newVal,oldVal){
  console.log($scope.dificulty);
});
```

On every model change it will get printed. BTW I havent used that directive. But I don't see the ng-change supported on the available properties for that directive.

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh, well I can get that to work, except I don't appear to have access to the difficultyID, which is mostly what I'm after.

Comment: try Initializing the variable first on your controller . So put $scope.dificulty = someValue